# No module named 'flask_ldap3_login'

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-login, ldap3

I am setting up flask login page with ldap3. I am using python 3.6.8 and using ldap3. After `pip3 install flask-ldap3-login` I am getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_ldap3_login'`

I found https://pypi.org/project/flask-ldap3-login/
Flask LDAP3 Login uses the ldap3 library, maintaining compatability with python 3.4 and backwards.
But Python 3.4 has reached end-of-life. Python 3.4.10 is the final release of 3.4.
I also tried `pip3 install python-ldap` but cant get ldap autentificate successfull.

```sh
(venv) $ sudo python3 run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from flask_ldap3_login import LDAP3LoginManager
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_ldap3_login'
(venv)$ pip3 install flask-ldap3-login
Requirement already satisfied: flask-ldap3-login in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (0.9.16)
Requirement already satisfied: ldap3>=2.0.7 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-ldap3-login) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-ldap3-login) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-wtf in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from flask-ldap3-login) (0.14.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.8 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from ldap3>=2.0.7->flask-ldap3-login) (0.4.6)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-ldap3-login) (0.15.5)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-ldap3-login) (2.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-ldap3-login) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask->flask-ldap3-login) (7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Flask-wtf->flask-ldap3-login) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->flask-ldap3-login) (1.1.1)
(venv)$ python
Python 3.6.8 (default, Jun 12 2019, 01:12:31)
[GCC 8.2.1 20180905 (Red Hat 8.2.1-3)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Expected result is app run.py run successfully.
Anybody runs flask_ldap3_login on newer version of python?
Or how ca i fix this, or no fix for python 3.6.8.

Thank you.

Comment: Why `sudo`? Can you change the port and try without `sudo` if you're using port 80. Consider Having an `nginx` reverse proxy when deploying flask applications.

Comment: Actually i tried that and you solved my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Running script without sudo privileges and everything works.
Thank you.